# How to add WordPress custom posts by front end forms

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom post type named gallery and its showing up nicely and works fine for me. My problem is that I don't want to allow my users to post their galleries from dashboard I want a way so that they can post there gallery images from front end by using upload buttons or any thing like forms etc. Is this possible to achieve in WordPress?

Kindly guide me in this regard, or is there any plugin which can do this task for me?

Comment: by using wp_insert_post() method have a look https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

Comment: This would be a better fit for [our wordpress site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/). If you are looking for php functions, both sites would go, but if you prefer a plugin, ask there instead. Anyway, add what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

- You can set and retrieve custom fields in code, either using [custom metaboxes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) or a plugin like [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) or [Pods](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pods/)
- You can set [capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#capabilities) when you register a post type to control what roles can access what.